# kendo ui angularjs grid edit

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I'm doing a POC for AngularJS and Kendo UI and I need to know how to save updated data on a kendo grid. I have inline editing enabled but can't hook into kendo UI to get the updated data. I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aMz7V/14/) but can't get the jsfiddle to work (sorry this is my first time creating a fiddle), so I have pasted the code below:

**JavaScript (controller code):**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['kendo.directives']);

myApp.controller("gridCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.assignments = {};

    $scope.assignments.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
            { StudentName: "John Smith", HomeWork: 9, HomeWork1: 12 },
            { StudentName: "Kodjo Adu", HomeWork: 5, HomeWork1: 15 },
            { StudentName: "Patrick smith", HomeWork: 10, HomeWork1: 19 },
            { StudentName: "Richard lomax", HomeWork: 8, HomeWork1: 18 },
            { StudentName: "Aglade Bone", HomeWork: 7, HomeWork1: 20 }
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    StudentName: { type: "string" },
                    HomeWork: { type: "number" },
                    HomeWork1: { type: "number" },
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 3,
    });

    $scope.assignments.columns = [
        { field: 'StudentName', title: 'Student Name' },
        { field: 'HomeWork', title: 'Home Work / 10' },
        { field: 'HomeWork1', title: 'Home Work / 20' }
    ];
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='gridCtrl'>
        <div kendo-grid k-data-source="assignments.dataSource" k-selectable="'row'"
         k-pageable='{ "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'
         k-columns='{{assignments.columns}}' k-sortable="true" k-editable="true" k-toolbar="['save','cancel']"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but it seems to me that this question would greatly benefit from more specific explanation of what you're trying to accomplish and in which way it doesn't work.

Comment: @Adi Inbar So basically when a user updates the values in the grid and clicks "save changes" I want to get to able to respond to that click event, grab the changed values and save it myself. As it stands it is being handled by Kendo. I have tried attaching a handler to "k-savachanges" but that doesn't work. Hope you understand the issue am having.

Answer (score 2):

So i figured it out, to handle to the save changes event i needed to do this

```
k-on-save-changes="saveChanges(kendoEvent)"
```

and just add the saveChanges function to the $scope in the controller.